# How to run tableau utility command using subprocess module in python 3

Tags: python, cmd, tableau-api

I am trying to write a function in python that takes name of a data source connection in tableau server and updates the extracts. The python code is supposed to use tableau utility command line to refresh the data source.

The problem that I have is python only passes the first argument in `subprocess.run` and ignores other argument like  `"refreshextract" ,"--server servername"`. My theory is based on the fact that when I run the script in command line, it only opens the tableau desktop and when I quit the tableau, the `std_out` result is `b''`.

I am really new to this stuff and I appreciate if you point me in the right direction.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import subprocess




def main():
    lst1 = os.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 2020.2\\bin")
    result = subprocess.run(["tableau", "refreshextract" ,"--server servername", "--username soroush" ,"--password 'PASS'" "--site site_id","--project 'project name'" ],capture_output=True)
    print("stdout:", result.stdout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the parameter `shell = True` in

```
result = subprocess.run(["tableau", "refreshextract" ,
"--server servername", "--username soroush" ,
"--password 'PASS'" "--site site_id","--project 'project name'" ],capture_output=True,shell = True)
```

solve my problem.